# Open-Source Repositories that use IoT Sensor Data for Smart Contracts and Blockchain

Tags: sensors, blockchains

In all honesty, I have only been reading blogs and papers about how IoT enabled Sensor data can be used with Blockchain along side with Smart Contracts for smart-industries, healthcare etc. but for a fact I have not come across a single repository that in fact achieves something. I have gone through [OriginTrail](https://origintrail.io) and they have repositories where the example of data structure for IoT sensor information is illustrated and I am now on a mission to survey some other tools where I can compare who is doing what.

I would like a list of open-source repositories or projects that actually have IoT, Smart Contracts and Blockchain technologies as their core driving technologies in order to see how they are actually being used.

Some Platforms already:

1. [Filament](https://filament.com) | Propreitary IoT Blockchain Solutions
2. [IoTChain](https://iotchain.io) | open-source
3. [IoTex](https://iotex.io)

Comment: Check out [this article](https://www.postscapes.com/blockchains-and-the-internet-of-things/) which has a fairly extensive list.  I didn't go into the research to figure out which ones would typically be used with smart contracts, though.